# Writing TIFF images on Windows with PHP file_put_contents

Tags: php, windows, tiff

The problem is, that it does work like a charm on Linux, but not on `Windows Server 2008 R2` with `PHP 5.3`.

The method, where I'm using `file_put_contents` writes JPEG images without any problems, but is not able to write the `TIFF` files.

Anybody seen such a behavior?

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to create the TIFF image? Do you get zero-byte files on Windows, or corrupted images, or what?

Comment: And where does the data come from? Is it binary all along? If it's interpreted as a string at some point, it might get corrupted in some cases but no others (apparently not in Linux but in Windows).

Comment: The data is binary and a result of a SOAP request, which does work. I compared the result of the SOAP request Windows/Linux and they are identically.